# Can't upload a file using wordpress upload functions

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I need to add logo upload functionality to a custom php plugin on wordpress.
I found this code on wordpress codex:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['editfile'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
if ( $movefile ) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    var_dump( $movefile);
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

Here is the form:

```
<form action="' . site_url('/edit-company/?cid=' . $_GET['cid']) . '" method="post">
                                                <label><b>Company Name:</b></label> <input type="text" name="editname" value="' . $company->company_name . '">
                                                <label><b>Address:</b></label> <input type="text" name="editaddress" value="' . $company->company_address . '">
                                                <label><b>Telephone:</b></label> <input type="text" name="edittelephone" value="' . $company->company_telephone . '">
                                                <label><b>Fax:</b></label> <input type="text" name="editfax" value="' . $company->company_fax . '">
                                                <label><b>Email:</b></label> <input type="text" name="editemail" value="' . $company->company_email . '">
                                                <label><b>Website:</b></label> <input type="text" name="editwebsite" value="' . $company->company_website . '">
                                                <label><b>Logo:</b></label> <input type="file" name="editfile" id="file">
                                                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                            </form>
```

If I submit a file to this it gives me the following error:

> File is valid, and was successfully uploaded. array(1) { ["error"]=>
>   string(212) "File is empty. Please upload something more substantial.
>   This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your
>   php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than
>   upload_max_filesize in php.ini." }

The file I am submitting is about 50kb in size. Uploading bigger or smaller files doesn't seem to make a difference.

I have no problem uploading files of any size in Wordpress admin do I wouldn't think php.ini or post max size is causing this.

If you have any tips or info on this please let me know. I have been stuck on this for quite some time now. Tried using simple upload script in vanilla PHP but that also doesn't seem to work so I am back at trying to get it done with wp functions.

UPDATE:
- tried setting the permissions of the upload folder to 777 - no help

Comment: I think you need permission on folder where you trying to upload files.

Comment: Would it be safe to set the permissions of the wp uploads folder to 775?

Comment: yes it would be safe to set permission 775.

Comment: Tried setting it to 775 and even 777 but still same response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that your upload form is not inside another form. Because once I got the same error as yours and the problem is because my upload form located inside another form.

Hope this can help.

**[updated]**

Your form is fine, but I see that the input field name and the post variable name that you catch is different

```
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];

<input type="file" name="editfile" id="file">
```

Those names must not be different. Try to edit it like this

```
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['editfile'];
```

**[updated]**

And also please add this to your form's attribute

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: I have updated the original question with the form code. To me it seems all OK.

Comment: Thanks but that was just me copying the unedited example code and not  the amended code I actually use which does have the same name 'editfile'. Sorry about not noticing this.

Comment: next time please copy your real code to avoid that. :)

btw, what about your another input field..??
do they work properly..??

Comment: Other input fields work just fine: they are processed by other code not shown there.

Comment: have you tried to see the var_dump of $_FILES['editfile'];..??

If it's still empty..something is blocking your file to be uploaded.

Comment: Thanks! It was the enctype attribute missing :)
Can't believe I forgot it. So all I had to do is add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form and it works.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include this. Though my edit still has to be reviewed by others. Or you could just add that piece of info to make your answer complete.